# Why Do We Include the Particular Solution When Solving for Arbitrary Constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given an ordinary differential equation with degree $n$, do we include the particular solution when solving for the arbitrary constants?

For example, given the first order ODE of a circuit:
$$
\frac{\text{dv}}{\text{dt}}+\frac{v}{RC}=\frac{V_s}{RC}
$$
with initial condition $\text{v}(0)=V_0$

we have
$$
\text{v}_c=ke^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\\
\text{v}_p=V_s\\
v=ke^{-\frac{t}{RC}}+V_s
$$
The $k$ is solved by including the particular solution to yield $$k=V_0-V_s$$

---

The example above makes use of the particular solution. My other question is, since the ODE is linear, can't we solve for the arbitrary constants without involving the particular solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question.
When you add the particular solution, that changes $v(0)$.  So if you align $v(0)$ before adding the particular, $v(0)$ will no longer be correct.

Comment: May I ask how do the initial condition change when a forcing function is present?

Comment: Then the particular solution will look similar to the forcing function, while the homogeneous solution still looks like exponential decay.  You still add them together then use $v(0)$ to decide on the precise homogeneous solution.

Comment: Oh!!! Thank You